# JavaScript- array size doubles after shuffling even with slice()

Tags: javascript, random, html-table

I have an array of 5 words that I want to randomly place on a section of an HTML table. When I run the code below, the keywords randomly appear on the table but their numbers are doubled (I get a total of 10 words on the grid). I am not sure why the cloning with slice does not work. I am new to JS and don't understand all its technicalities yet. Any feedback on what I might be doing wrong would be appreciated.

```
var keywords = ["s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5"];
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temp, randomIndex;
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;
    temp = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temp;
} 
 return array;
}
function drawBoard(rows, cols){
    var grid = document.getElementById("grid");
    grid.className = 'grid';
    for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++){
        var row = grid.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
        for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++){
            var cell = row.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
        }       
    }
    grid.rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML = "START";
    grid.rows[7].cells[7].innerHTML = "FINISH";
    const filtered = Array.from(grid.querySelectorAll('td')).filter(({cellIndex, parentElement: {rowIndex}}) => rowIndex  && rowIndex < ROW - 1 && cellIndex && cellIndex < COL -1);
    shuffle(filtered);
    const sliced = filtered.slice(0, keywords.length);
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * keywords.length);
    sliced.forEach((cell, index) => cell.innerHTML = keywords[index]);
    return grid;
}
const table = document.body.appendChild(drawBoard(ROW, COL));
```

Comment: Is it because you're not deleting the old words?

Comment: old words? I am not sure if I understand. Could you clarify?

Comment: When you call `drawBoard`, you are adding cells to your table. What if you call `drawBoard` twice though? The old words are still on the table, but you are going to add 5 more, so you end up with 10 elements. Check out dgeare's answer below.

Comment: how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Try `grid.innerHTML = "";` right after getting the element, before the `for` loop and run your code again to see if the bug persists.

Comment: if you meant, right after "var grid = document.getElementById("grid");" it did not work.

Comment: Ok it worked with a quick change in the function parameters: function drawBoard(rows, cols, grid){
 grid.innerHTML = "";  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance you might be calling `drawBoard` twice? I only get 5 entries when I execute the code (snippet below)

```js
var ROW = 8;
var COL = 8;

var keywords = ["s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5"];
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temp, randomIndex;
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;
    temp = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temp;
} 
 return array;
}


function drawBoard(rows, cols){
    var grid = document.getElementById("grid");
    grid.className = 'grid';
    for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++){
        var row = grid.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
        for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++){
            var cell = row.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
        }       
    }
    
    
    grid.rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML = "START";
    grid.rows[7].cells[7].innerHTML = "FINISH";
    const filtered = Array.from(grid.querySelectorAll('td')).filter(({cellIndex, parentElement: {rowIndex}}) => rowIndex  && rowIndex < ROW - 1 && cellIndex && cellIndex < COL -1);
    shuffle(filtered);
    const sliced = filtered.slice(0, keywords.length);
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * keywords.length);
    sliced.forEach((cell, index) => cell.innerHTML = keywords[index]);
    return grid;
}
const table = document.body.appendChild(drawBoard(ROW, COL));
```

```html
<table id='grid'></table>
```

Comment: the only other place is when i do this:   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", drawBoard, false);

Comment: @coder that seems like it would do it. `drawBoard` would be executed once by the  event listener and once with `const table = document.body.appendChild(drawBoard(ROW, COL));`. The previous values aren't being cleared out in `drawBoard` so you are just adding new values (and rows to the table every call). I suspect if you inspected `#grid` with the devtools you would see it had more rows than you expected.

Comment: thanks so much. yes this was another reason for the duplicates!